# Copying Child Nodes under different Parent

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT and got stuck with this issue.
Input XML

```
<Root>
 <Family>
   <Entity>
     <SomeElement1/>
     <Child1>
       <Element1/>
     </Child1>
     <Child2>
       <Element2/>
     </Child2>
     <Entity>
     <SomeElement1/>
     <Child1>
       <Element111/>
     </Child1>
     <Child2>
       <Element222/>
     </Child2>
   </Entity>
  </Entity>
 </Family>
</Root>
```

Output Xml

```
<Response>
 <EntityRoot>
  <SomeElement1/>
 </EntityRoot>

 <Child1Root>
   <Element1>
 </Child1Root>

 <Child2Root>
   <Element2>
 </Child2Root>

 <MetadataEntityRoot>
  <SomeElement1/>
 </MetadataEntityRoot>

 <Child1Root>
   <Element111>
 </Child1Root>

 <Child2Root>
   <Element222>
 </Child2Root>
</Response>
```

I know how to copy everything from the input xml. But not sure how would exclude child elements and then copy them again in a different root element.

```
<!-- Copy everything -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

**Tried this** based on the given answer

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Entity">
      <EntityRoot>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[not(self::Child1 | self::Child2)]" />
      </EntityRoot>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Child1 | Child2" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Child1">
      <Child1Root><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></Child1Root>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Child2">
      <Child2Root><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></Child2Root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But got the output as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
 <Family>
   <EntityRoot>
     <SomeElement1/>
   </EntityRoot>
   <Child1Root>
       <Element1/>
    </Child1Root>
    <Child2Root>
       <Element2/>
    </Child2Root>
 </Family>
</Root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the "copy everything" identity template you already have, you just add specific templates that match the elements you want to process differently.  To rename `Child1` to `Child1Root` you can use

```
<xsl:template match="Child1">
  <Child1Root><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></Child1Root>
</xsl:template>
```

and similarly to rename `Child2` to `Child2Root` and `Root` to `Response`.  For `Entity` you can think of the process as creating an `EntityRoot` containing (the result of applying templates to) all the child elements *except* Child1 and Child2, then apply templates to these two afterwards, outside the `EntityRoot` element:

```
<xsl:template match="Entity">
  <EntityRoot>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[not(self::Child1 | self::Child2)]" />
  </EntityRoot>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Child1 | Child2" />
</xsl:template>
```

To strip out a layer entirely (in this case `Family`) but still include its children you can use a template without a `copy`:

```
<xsl:template match="Family">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: It did not work for me. Update my question based on your answer.

Comment: @HimanshuYadav I've edited my answer to make it clearer that the templates I suggest are _in addition to_ the identity template you started with in the question, not _instead of_ it.  The identity template says "keep everything the same except the things I want to change" and the additional templates I suggest are the "things I want to change".

Comment: Thanks. Just the root elements. How would I filter out root elements `<Root> <Family>`? Please see the updates.I know it would be needing a phony root elements. Lets say that is `<Response>`.

Comment: @HimanshuYadav I've added a bit more detail.  XSLT doesn't have to be complicated, you just need to get comfortable with the basic building blocks (the identity template, empty templates to delete elements, simple renaming templates like the `Child1` one, and "ignore me but keep my children" like the `Family` one) and think of your problem in a data-driven way rather than a procedural one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for being so patient. It works absolutely fine. Just fails with one condition when I have recursive `EntityRoot`. If you want I can ask this as a separate question but I have updated my question for that case.

Comment: I have got it myself. Thanks again.

Comment: I am not able to get root `Response` element on the transformed xml. Tried multiple things but no luck.

Comment: @HimanshuYadav it should be the same pattern as for `Child1` - you want to rename the `Root` element from the input as `Response` in the output.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I will take care of it now.